# Avoiding Static method for testability when creating a sort of Factory

Tags: java, unit-testing

When refactoring some code I found that I had a `new` call which created a concrete class.

I was looking for a way to avoid the call to create a concrete class and improve testability so I created a sort of Factory which was responsible for returning me an instance. I then, using Spring constructor injection, inject the factory to the System Under Test.

However now I'm faced with a question about making the method in my factory static while at the same time having good testability. According to Misko Hevery, [Static Methods are Death to testability](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html) however I do not have a clear idea what to do to remove the call to new, have good unit tests, and avoid the static method call.

This is an extract from the class that uses the factory. I am testing methods in this class that make use of the constructed (and mocked) columnFamilyTemplate:

```java
protected AlertFieldMatcher(ColumnFamilyTemplateBuilder columnFamilyTemplateBuilder, Keyspace keyspace,
                            T2JsonUtilInterface jsonUtil) {
    this.columnFamilyTemplate = columnFamilyTemplateBuilder.build(keyspace, CF_ALERT);
    this.jsonUtil = jsonUtil;
}
```

And this is the factory, which I now have to mock in tests for methods in the SUT (above):

```java
public class DefaultColumnFamilyTemplateBuilder 
                                         implements ColumnFamilyTemplateBuilder {


   @Override
   public ColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String> build(Keyspace keyspace, 
                                                       String columnFamily) {
       ColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String> builtTemplate = 
                                                 new ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String>
                                                    (keyspace, 
                                                      columnFamily,
                                                      StringSerializer.get(), 
                                                      StringSerializer.get());
       return builtTemplate;
   }

   ...
}
```

The only option I see is to leave my Factory type object as is, ie not make the method static.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Why would you make the factory method static? The reason you shouldn't do that (for testability) is that you can inject *another* factory, that instantiates a test object, rather than a real one.

Comment: I'm asking because I didn't have a strong answer for my boss when suggested maybe making it static. Leaving it as is, as you say (I think) I am able to mock the DefaultColumnFamilyTemplateBuilder and use a mock implementation in my tests. As a static I suppose I can't do that.

Comment: I also just noticed that I've mixed terms using as name that implies the known Builder pattern with a Factory object

Comment: I don't see any problem for testing static method without side effects

Comment: @mishadoff I am not testing the Factory, but something that uses it. Additionally, the `build` method on the Factory is coded to the interface which cannot contain a static method as of Java 7. As long as I want to mock the Factory, it appears I need a non-static method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to remove "new" from your application, you need some mechanism for creating objects on your behalf. There are three mechanisms you might want to check out.

The first is dependency injection. DI containers allow you to take a more interface-based approach and choose what implementations to use at runtime. Spring is the most popular DI container while CDI is the new "standard". DI is fine, but it's not necessarily the kind of thing you want to introduce late in a project.

The second mechanism is the Java ServiceLoader which allows you to change implementation of components by adding and removing files from your classpath. You might find this a bit fiddly.

The last mechanism would be to use a static method (!!!!) that reads in a property which is the class name of your factory object and use Class.forName().newInstance() to create the factory object for you. This might be the simplest approach. It gives you a seam to inject a new mock factory into.

Avoiding statics is a good idea but they have their place. Use them if you understand the trade-offs involved.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I do inject my factory into the constructor using Spring. The question for me is if I end up converting the method to static, in which case I will mock static using Powermock, or I leave it as is and keep my Factory coded to an interface

Comment: I would say leave it coded to an interface. Spring is doing the heavy lifting for you and testing should be straightforward. I would say that the whole issue of using statics and new disappears if you are doing DI - that's what I would tell your boss.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create explicitly a factory.

Extract the the creation of the new instance to a protected method in your class, exactly the same as if you were creating a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) but providing `new ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate(...)` as default implementation.

In your unit tests your sut will be a partially mocked version of the class, mocking the factory method, instead of the real class. With this approach the only code untested will be the factory method, that is one single line. For the partial mocking you can use [EasyMock IMockBuilder](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/IMockBuilder.html).